# How to change temporarily font size in text console in openSUSE?

Tags: linux, fonts, console

I found several answers already but all of them are focused on changing size for good, i.e. at Lilo/Grub level. I don't want this though.

So, key issues:

1. changing size on-fly, I would like to increase size, and 5 minutes later, decrease it back
2. it is question about text console, not terminal running in X11

openSUSE 11.4 if this matters. Thank you in advance.

*I am only interested in size of the font, not in typeface of it.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
setfont /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/$font
```

to change the font in the console, and then to revert back, just

```
setfont
```

Once you determine where Suse keeps these fonts, with

```
locate consolefonts
```

pick a larger one to set and away you go...

There is more detail here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Console_fonts

Comment: Thank you very much, great reading! openSUSE has the same location for fonts, so there was no problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can also press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the number pad <kbd>+</kbd> sign
it'll show three mode of window size and you can get the larger font on third attempt.

Comment: That works for console? I doubt it, but for a terminal emulator it would work.