# Can I increase brightness of text in Arch shell?

Tags: shell, arch-linux, terminal

I just installed Arch Linux.  All I have right now is the shell.  The text is very difficult to read on a black background.  My eyesight is fine.

Can I change the brightness of the text, or can I only change the font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the TTY, ie., not a terminal emulator running in X, you can change the font to a larger size, or a different font using `setfont`, or you can change the colours that the font is displayed in, which may increase the legibility for you.

For the former, see my answer to [How to temporarily change font size in text console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12132/how-to-change-temporarily-font-size-in-text-console-in-opensuse).

For the latter, see my answer to [How to colourize the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/how-to-colorize-output-of-ls).